# Will JSch continue to execute the command even if the java code terminates?

Tags: java, remote-server, jsch

I am trying to execute a command on a remote-server using Jsch library in java.

```
 ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
 channel.connect();
```

Now I expect the command to take some time to run in the remote-server (say 30 minutes). 
During this time if java program is aborted, 
What happens to the command running in the server?
Does it continue running?
Does it abort?

Answer (score 0):

Jsch does not inherently clean up sessions and channels, you have to specifically close them, or else they will persist until terminated by the host you are connected to.

However if your java program closes and the JVM cleans up, the session will terminate on your end, and most host systems are going to time you out before your program finishes.

You need to have your Java program run the program in the background as a Daemon.  That will allow the command to continue processing after you have disconnected your session.

ChannelExec.setCommand("myCommand > /dev/null 2>&1 &");